# why does smarty function date_format get wrong time

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, smarty

```
echo date('Y-m-d',time())
```

i get 2012-07-16 ,but when smarty output is

```
{$smarty.now | date_format : "%Y-%I-%d"}
```

i get 2012-04-16

I have been sured the time_zone is seted right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `%I` is hours ... try :

```
{$smarty.now | date_format : "%Y-%m-%d"}
```

> %m - month as a decimal number (range 01 to 12)

[Docs are here for `date_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format)

Comment: If you're using Smarty3 you can also use the date() format: `{$smarty.now|date_format:"Y-m-d"}`